# What does it mean to measure the EM field of a charged particle?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm kind of confused. When we measure the EM field of an particle (like an electron), what exactly are we measuring?  Are we measuring the position of where the EM field is, the strength of the EM field?
Does measuring the EM field of a particle collapse its wave function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EM field isn't attached to a specific particle nor does it exist in one place, it just exists everywhere all the time regardless of whether there are charged particles about.

A charged particle interacts with the EM field, causing it to change in a predictable way, and this change can be measured, but you're not measuring the particle when you do this. You're just measuring the EM field and comparing it with a measurement you might have taken earlier before there was a particle.

Comment: How do we measure the EM field when there is a particle there? Does it collapse the wave function of the particle when we do this?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: It's difficult to talk about fixed numbers of particles and particle wavefunctions when considering interacting fields, as the full description is given by QFT where the concept of a single particle doesn't really exist.

Ultimately, I believe it is the case that the field operators do *not* commute with the position operator, due to them being built out of ladder operators which are built from both the position and momentum operators. Since momentum and position do not commute, the ladder operators do not commute with position.

Comment: Essentially this means that measuring the field will *not* collapse the position wavefunction of a particle (since the field and position do not share eigenstates due to their non-commutativity), but it *will* affect the position of the particle somehow.

I appreciate this is all a bit vague but I'm not 100% clear on field theory myself so hopefully someone a bit more experienced can give you a better answer.

Comment: Do you think penning traps measure the change in the EM field that a charged particle induces in it?

Comment: Heres a link http://depts.washington.edu/uwptms/research.html